# Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

Trying to make a Rest API using Entity Framework Core and OData.
I have 2 models. One named InvoiceModel and another one named InvoiceLinesModel

Basically the InvoiceModel are the basic information about the invoice, which then has a collection of lines(InvoiceLines) with the items(vat, discount etc.)

See here the two models:

**InvoiceModel**

```
public class InvoiceModel
{
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public Guid Customer { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal VatTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
    public string YourReference { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(InvoiceLinesModel.Number))]
    public ICollection<InvoiceLinesModel> Lines { get; set; }
}
```

**InvoiceLinesModel**

```
public class InvoiceLinesModel
{
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LineNumber")]
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }

    public Guid Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceExcl { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceIncl { get; set; }
    public decimal DefaultPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal VatPercentage { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDiscount { get; set; }
    public string Instruction { get; set; }
    //public InvoiceModel Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

Now, Inside my controller I try to fetch the data from 2 procs.
Then, with a foreach I want to add the InvoiceLines to the collection of the Invoice Object.

```
 public IQueryable<InvoiceModel> GetInvoices()
        {
            IQueryable<InvoiceModel> Invoices = null;
            ICollection<InvoiceLinesModel> InvoiceLines = null;

            Invoices = db.Invoices.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_InvoiceMain_sel");
            InvoiceLines = db.InvoiceLines.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_InvoiceDetail_sel").ToList();
            foreach (var item in Invoices)
            {
                item.Lines = InvoiceLines.Where(m => m.Number == item.Number).ToList();
            }
            return Invoices;
```

The problem is that I get an error on this line since I've changed the actionresult to IQueryAble, this as I need to be able to use the $expand OData functionality to return Collections with OData, right?

```
    Invoices = db.Invoices.FromSql("SIP_API_MONDIA_InvoiceMain_sel");
```

The error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The relationship from
>   'InvoiceLinesModel' to 'InvoiceModel.Lines' with foreign key
>   properties {'Number' : string} cannot target the primary key {'Id' :
>   Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set
>   of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.'

Edit: In our case, the number(which is a string.. Don't ask me why it's not named differently) is the key to compare/link.

As you can see in the controller:

```
  foreach (var item in Invoices)
            {
                item.Lines = InvoiceLines.Where(m => m.Number == item.Number).ToList();
            }
```